I'd like to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 11 but may have made a misstep because I made the USB boot media using master boot record (MBR)
I have a new computer running Windows 11.

I installed Ubuntu 24 by making a bootable USB using Rufus, but I think it made a MBR (instead of GPT) to burn the image on the USB thumb drive. I had to disable secure boot in the BIOS menu but was able to boot using the USB. During the installation process I selected boot alongside Windows and I believe it made a partition. During the installation process it asked me to remove the bootable media and it restarted, however it rebooted into Windows without an obvious option to select which operating system to use when booting the computer.
I did some reading and saw it may be recommended to first make a partition using windows diskmgt.msc. Here is what my partitions look like in Windows. I'm not sure where the partition Ubuntu made or where the Ubuntu OS was installed. You can see in the image the USB too.


How can I choose which OS to use when booting the computer? (Windows 11 or Ubuntu)?
Did I install Ubuntu incorrectly for my computer which uses UEFI mode?


If you do not want UEFI Secure boot you should be ok. I would prefer that you have an ESP on second drive, but Ubuntu defaults to an existing ESP unless told otherwise. You should be able to directly boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu like you booted USB flash drive. But some like HP require you to change boot order in UEFI settings, some like Acer require "trust" setting on unknown boot labeled entry.  What brand/model system.

To confirm you have Ubuntu installed can you run 'gparted' (equiv of what you did from WIN11) from the USB install media and post the results in your original question.
